# Two tsconfig files with Dependency issue

Tags: json, visual-studio, typescript, tsconfig

I have solution with two ts config files.
The solution has [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZqS.jpg) folder structure.

Root tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "outFile":  "Test/Namespace.js" 
    }
}
```

Test\tsconfig.json is empty.

Test.ts properly works only if Namespace.d.ts is created, but build crashes in this case. Obvious reason for this is the compilation order, Test\tsconfig.json is compiled first.

Is there a way to change the compilation order for tsconfig files, or continue the build despite other tsconfig errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"files"` propoerty in your tsconfig.json to specify the order of the files emitted to the outFile.

for instance:
`json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outFile":  "Test/Namespace.js" 
  },
  "files": [
     "namespace.ts",
     "test.ts"
  ]
}`

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-control-file-ordering-in-combined-output---out- for more details.

Comment: Actually, I'm talking about another thing. The problem consists in the compilation order of two "tsconfig.json" files. So, it's not about a compilation order inside one of "tsconfig.json". File "Test.ts" has dependency on output declaration file of root "tsconfig.json" . But d.ts file is not generated before. I have attached a simple solution with this problem to [issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12432) on github.

Comment: The order in MSBuild is the order they appear in the file. make sure the two tsconifg.json files are listed in this order. you can also put them in two different MSBuild projects and add a dependency from one to the other.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and even though my two tsconfig files are in the correct order, the second one is still complaining about a missing file generated by the first one. A diag log of the msbuild process shows that the tasks appear to be executed in the right order, but perhaps they're being executed concurrently?